# jQuery animation only if ajax information is not the same

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a timer every 20 seconds using setInterval, it uses jQuery's ajax function load() to set the toparticles div with the information from another URL on site. Once that load is successful, it performs a jQuery highlight effect on the first article in the toparticles div. All articles on both places are held in their own seperate table, so I use #toparticles table:first.

I only want to perform the loading into the toparticles div, AND the animation if the first article is not the same.

So the concept is as follows:
Every 20 seconds:
Check this url, if the first table isn't equal to the first table of the page you're on, reload the entire div with that url's information, then perform highlight animation.

My current code:

```
setInterval(function() {
$("#toparticles").load("http://myarticles/feed/of/top/articles", function()
{
$("#toparticles table:first").effect("highlight", {color:"#f2f37f"}, 1000);});
}, 20000);
```

Thanks if you can provide any help.

Comment: Can you have some sort of id for the first article so you can easily test if it is the same ? or do you have to check the entire html of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive approach (*best would be to have some sort of id*) is

```
setInterval(function() {
  var first_html = $("#toparticles table:first").text();
  $("#toparticles").load("http://myarticles/feed/of/top/articles", function()
   {
     if ( first_html == $("#toparticles table:first").text() )
     {
        $("#toparticles table:first").effect("highlight", {color:"#f2f37f"}, 1000);
     }
  });
}, 20000);
```

It stores the **text** of the first table in a variable before the ajax call, and then compares it to the new first table. (*i only check for text, you could change that to `.html()` to check for the whole html structure if you want that level of detail*)

Comment: Doesn't your conditional check if the current pages first table is equal to the same thing? not the others? Seems that way after working with it, maybe some variation of "this"?

Comment: @Dan, the callback method is called after the new content has been added to the element. So the `first_html` variable holds the pre-ajax content, and the new `$("#toparticles table:first").text()` returns the post-ajax content.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably change your request to use jQuery.ajax().  It has an "ifModified" option.  From the docs:

> ifModifiedBoolean
> Default: false
>
> Allow the request to be successful only if the response has changed since the last request. This is done by checking the Last-Modified header. Default value is false, ignoring the header. In jQuery 1.4 this technique also checks the 'etag' specified by the server to catch unmodified data.

[jQuery.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Also, I haven't checked myself but it seems as though they have an example that uses the `.load()` function's call back:

```
$("#success").load("/not-here.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```